# Extension of Bernstein's example

Tags: probability, geometry

There is a Bernstein's example of 3 dependent events such that each 2 of them are independent (tetrahedron with marked vertices which is thrown from above). I need to build an example of 4 dependent events such that each 3 of them are independent together. (probably it's worth to think about cube, but I can not understand how to do it). Please, help me out!

Comment: If the example you are thinking about has $\frac{2^3}{2}=4$ equally likely cases with a parity condition, you might try the same thing with  $\frac{2^4}{2}=8$ equally likely cases with a parity condition.  Imagine it as alternate vertices of a hypercube in the same way that your 3D model uses  alternate vertices of a cube amounting to a tetrahedron.